# Should I be concerned with DDMS message in the console area of Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

After many hours, I have finally installed the proper version of Eclipse (3.6.2), the SDK (16.0.1), and the ADT Plugin for eclipse. I was able to "plug in" the SDK starter kit with no problem. Then, when I went to install the latest API 4.0.3 (window --> SDK manager ...), in the lower part of the window in the console (it is headed by "DDMS") the following message was displayed:

```
[2011-12-30 16:23:03 - DDMS] DDMS files not found: C:\Program Files    (x86)\eclipse\platform-tools\adb.exe C:\Program Files (x86)\eclipse\tools\hprof-conv.exe  C:\Program Files (x86)\eclipse\tools\traceview.bat 
[2011-12-30 16:47:18 - DeviceMonitor] Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
[2011-12-30 16:47:19 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 1
```

I believe that the something is looking for DDMS within the eclipse folder and not the Android folder. If this is problem or otherwise, how do I fix it? Thanks in advance!

BTW I am using windows 7 (64 bit)

Answer (score 2):

First of all check if there are or there aren't those files. If there aren't they you should have some problems during installation and the best way is to re-install SDK.

However, if you will find there those files than you can restart adb, that mean eclipse. In extreme cases computer.

Comment: The files exist, but under a different directory. They are located within the Android folder in my Program files(x86) folder, but they are being searched for within the eclipse folder in the Program files (x86) folder.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to all of you, I also fixed all my errors, which included some listed here.
Someone on another site also recommended the following, which fixed most (if not all) of
my errors:

"Try changing the ADB connection timeout. I think it defaults that to 5000ms and I changed mine to 10000ms to get rid of that problem. If you are in Eclipse, you can do this by going through Window -> Preferences and then it is in DDMS under Android."

In my case I had to go to the following (in Eclipse of course)

Windows->Preferences->Android->DDMS

-jaime

Answer (score 0):

I had the same "DDMS files not found..." problem. I fixed it by making sure that the Android SDK path is set correctly in Eclipse (which is "C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk" on my machine). This can be done in Eclipse->Windows->Preferences->Android->SDK Location. Note that if you are running Windows 7, it is best to run Eclipse and SDK Manager with the "Run as administrator" option.

I am running Windows 7 32-bit, Eclipse Indigo SR1, Android SDK r16.